# increment starting printing address in assembly

Tags: assembly, masm

I have the folowing code:

```
mov   ecx, 0
mov   eax, offset ReadWritten
RottenApple:
    push ecx
    push eax

    push 0
    push eax
    push 1
    push offset bytearray
    push consoleOutHandle
    call WriteConsole

    pop eax
    pop ecx
    inc     ecx
    inc     eax
    cmp     ecx, 10
    jne     RottenApple
```

The intention is to print, if the user input was "123456", fist 1, then 2, etc... But it only print 10 1's. Whats wrong with incrementing the offset,and why doesn't it make any diference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that `eax` is destroyed by the call to `WriteConsole` (it will contain the return value) so you have to save it just like you do with `ecx`.

**Update**:

On closer look, you are calling the `WriteConsole` with wrong arguments. You want to increment the offset, as you say in the question, but you are not doing that.
Try something like:

```
    mov   ecx, 0
    mov   eax, offset bytearray
RottenApple:
    push ecx
    push eax

    push 0
    push offset ReadWritten
    push 1
    push eax
    push consoleOutHandle
    call WriteConsole

    pop eax
    pop ecx
    inc     ecx
    inc     eax
    cmp     ecx, 10
    jne     RottenApple
```

Comment: Even if I do push/pop eax it still only prints 10 1's.I've updated the code.

Comment: Ok, why do you `push 1  push eax`, I thought that I could just change what the first offset was. Didn't see any different on the documentation.

Comment: `WriteConsole` takes 5 arguments, the handle, the buffer, the number of bytes to write, a pointer where the number of bytes actually written is returned, and a reserved 0. The `push 1` is the number of bytes to write. The `push eax` is the buffer, this is incremented each time to move to the next byte.

Comment: Ah, so `push offset ReadWritten` isnt what's going to be written?

Comment: Right. See the [msdn documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687401%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which says _"A pointer to a variable that receives the number of characters actually written."_

Comment: Damn... I had understood that bytearray would be that.